# PostCss doesn't import variable file

Tags: javascript, css, variables, gulp, postcss

I have installed `postcss-import` and `postcss-simple-vars`. I want to save all my color choices in a single file and then just use $orange instead of the hexcode whenever I need to. It is not working at the moment.

If I include the variable name+hexcode (`$orange: #ffa500"`) on top of my main css file, the value gets converted just fine (`.button{color: $orange;}`. But if I save the variable in a separate file, it is not finding it (I get 'undefined variable' error in my command line upon running gulp watch).

At the moment, my file structure is following:

> app/assets/styles/modules/_variables.css (with the $orange: #ffa500"),
>   app/assets/styles/modules/_global.css (with all global settings, e.g.
>   border-box) app/assets/styles/styles.css (this file has all the
>   @import statements: @import "normalize.css", @import
>   "modules/_global", @import "modules/_variables").

`Normalize.css` and `_global.css` gets imported (and compiled into `app/temp/styles`) just fine. But not the `_variables.css` file! Can someone explain what is going on?

This is my gulp setup:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch'),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
simplevars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
nested = require('postcss-nested'),
cssImport = require('postcss-import');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')
        .pipe(postcss([cssImport, simplevars, nested, autoprefixer]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/styles'));
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From last closed issue on [postcss-simple-vars GitHub's project](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-simple-vars/issues/61), by PostCSS author and maintainer of this plugin:

> In PostCSS logic is different.
>   You import _variables.pcss to styles.pcss.
>   Not to global state.

(I replaced a and c by the naming of your files)
So you'd need to import your variables in (each of / all) your other "partials" (and make sure it doesn't output CSS rules to your CSS countless times. Or if it's the case that your minifier takes care of that)

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid having to import my variables in all other partials, although it was always an option. I kept on playing with it and realised that I had to rearrange my file (app/assets/styles/styles.css) with all the partials. As soon as I put @import ("modules/_variables") before any other files that depend on _variables, it worked. Such a silly mistake.

Comment: That wouldn't be unexpected, as Sass did it first :) Related: LESS has a great option: [`@import (reference)`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options), kind of "FYI"